# Error while opening eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Tags: eclipse, file, logging, configuration, ide

I am a user of eclipse, I have downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java EE Web developers, I have extracted all the files and after opening the eclipse  I am getting an error called "An error has occured. See the log file. 
C:/eclipse/configuration/1590405511054.log" Please help me with this. 
I am using a 64-bit machine and I have already installed eclipse java mars and it is working properly.

Comment: You need to look at that log and tell us what it says.

Comment: !MESSAGE Startup error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
 
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.

Comment: [edit] your question and add  the full message